# Unable to send SIGUSR1 signals to another process results in closing of my terminal

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, posix

I was trying to fork processes and make them in a topology of a binary tree of N+1 nodes (1 is for the root) and then each process can send signals to process with pids ranging from [parent_pid-N,pid+N] (inclusive). I try sending the custom signal that is SIGUSR1, it terminates my terminal. I am guessing it happens because SIGUSR1's default action is to terminate and one of the process signals the process which has opened the terminal application, leading to terminal closing. So I added sleep(5) so that, my signal handlers are attached before sending signal
You can take a look at my code, maybe you can help me. I have also attached the logs. [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void tree() {

    int idx = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        int left;

        if (2 * idx > N + 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        left = fork();
        if (left == 0)
        {
            idx *= 2;
            continue;
        }

        int right ;
        if (2 * idx + 1 > N + 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        right = fork();
        if (right == 0)
        {
            idx = 2 * idx + 1;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }


}
void sigHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *context)
{

    printf("Signal received\n");
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    int lvl = (N + 1) / 2;
    int root = getpid();

    //A = atoi(argv[2]);
    //S = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("I am root %d\n", root);
    //points = N;
    //validPIDs = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    //int counter = 0;
    struct sigaction siga;
    siga.sa_sigaction = *sigHandler;
    siga.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO;

    if ( sigaction(SIGUSR1, &siga, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf(" Error in applying signal handler\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    tree();

    int pid = getpid();
    int ppid = getppid();
    int status;
    for (int id = ppid - N; id <= pid + N; id++)
    {
        printf("from: %d,to :%d\n", getpid(), id);
        sleep(5);

        status = kill(id, SIGUSR1);
        sleep(5);

    }
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are sending signals to your parent id, which is the terminal.  Also to other innocent victims.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text — if it's important, show the text in the question directly.

Comment: Do not do arithmetic with process IDs. It makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @stark I am sending signals to innocent victims, I know shouldn't they not terminate because I have attached a handler to the signal

Answer (score 0):

You are picking "random" processes to send signals tonwith your `for` loop. PIDs are not given in any particular way you can rely on.

*You need to get the PIDs in some other way, such as return value of `fork` (the normal way to manage child processes) or reading from a pid file (if target process can be confgired to write a PID file), or even searching through all processes (like `killall` command does).*

---

About your comment on installing signal handler:  You install signal handler in your own processes, but you are killing other "random" processes, which may not have this signal handler. You can't install a signal handler on these.